# ASP.NET Dynamic link button

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a dynamic link during page_init even and binding onclick to a link button.On click of dynamic link is able post back but it is not raising a onclick event (hitting a on click event in debug mode). Page postback and shows up a blank page without triggering a event. Please can anyone tell what I am doing wrong in the following code. I am using vs2005(ASp.Net 2.0).Please see first  switch case where I am dynamically creating a link button.

```
public partial class ChooseRole : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public Int32 ismId;
    public DataTable UserCredentialsDT;
    public DataTable dsUserDetails = null;
    public String strPage = "";
    protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton lnkAdmin;

    //protected System.Web.UI.WebControls.PlaceHolder PlaceHolderRoles;

    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session[PresentationConstant.USERCREDENTIALS] != null)
        {
            dsUserDetails = (DataTable)Session[PresentationConstant.USERCREDENTIALS];
            ismId = Convert.ToInt32(dsUserDetails.Rows[0][0].ToString());
        }

        Helper.validateRoleAuthentication(PresentationConstant.PAGE_CHOOSEROLE);
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {            
            if (Session[PresentationConstant.USERCREDENTIALS] != null)
            {
                UserCredentialsDT = (DataTable)Session[PresentationConstant.USERCREDENTIALS];

                //Sorting the roles
                DataView v = UserCredentialsDT.DefaultView;
                v.Sort = "roleName";
                UserCredentialsDT = v.ToTable();

                Int32 ismId = Convert.ToInt32(UserCredentialsDT.Rows[0][0].ToString());

                for (int i = 0; i < UserCredentialsDT.Rows.Count; i++)
                {

                    switch (Convert.ToInt32(UserCredentialsDT.Rows[i]["RoleId"]))
                    {
                        case (int)Helper.UserRole.Administrator:

                            //Session[AppConstants.ROLEID] = UserCredentialsDT.Rows[i]["RoleId"];
                             //LinkButton link = new LinkButton();
                             //{
                             //    link.Text = "Test< /br>";
                             //    link.ID = "TestButton";
                             //    link.Click += new EventHandler(TestClicked);


                             //}
                             //PlaceHolderRoles.Controls.Add(link);
                            lnkAdmin = new LinkButton();
                            lnkAdmin.EnableViewState = true;
                            lnkAdmin.Text = "Administrator" + "<br />";
                            lnkAdmin.ID = "lnkAdmin";

                            this.lnkAdmin.Click += new EventHandler(this.lnkAdmin_Click);
                            this.PlaceHolderRoles.Controls.Add(lnkAdmin);


                            //lnkAdmin.Visible = true;

                            break;


                        case (int)Helper.UserRole.KeyHolder:
                            Session[AppConstants.ROLEID] = UserCredentialsDT.Rows[i]["RoleId"];
                            String strPage;
                            LinkButton lnkSM = new LinkButton();
                            lnkSM.EnableViewState = true;
                            lnkSM.Text = "Manager / Key Holder" + "<br />";
                            lnkSM.ID = "lnkSM" + i.ToString();
                            PlaceHolderRoles.Controls.Add(lnkSM);
                            lnkSM.Visible = true;
                            strPage = GetStoresForStoreManager_Table(ismId);
                            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(strPage))
                            {
                                lnkSM.PostBackUrl = strPage;
                            }
                            break;

                        case (int)Helper.UserRole.DistrictManager:
                            Session[AppConstants.ROLEID] = UserCredentialsDT.Rows[i]["RoleId"];
                            LinkButton lnkDM = new LinkButton();
                            lnkDM.EnableViewState = true;
                            lnkDM.Text = "District Manager" + "<br />";
                            lnkDM.ID = "lnkDM" + i.ToString();
                            PlaceHolderRoles.Controls.Add(lnkDM);
                            lnkDM.Visible = true;
                            lnkDM.PostBackUrl = PresentationConstant.ASPX_DMREPORTS;
                            break;

                        case (int)Helper.UserRole.ARD:
                            Session[AppConstants.ROLEID] = UserCredentialsDT.Rows[i]["RoleId"];
                            LinkButton lnkARD = new LinkButton();
                            lnkARD.EnableViewState = true;
                            lnkARD.Text = "ARD" + "<br />";
                            lnkARD.ID = "lnkARD" + i.ToString();
                            PlaceHolderRoles.Controls.Add(lnkARD);
                            lnkARD.Visible = true;
                            lnkARD.PostBackUrl = PresentationConstant.ASPX_ARDREPORTS;
                            break;

                        case (int)Helper.UserRole.TeamAdvisor:
                            Session[AppConstants.ROLEID] = UserCredentialsDT.Rows[i]["RoleId"];
                            LinkButton lnkTeamAdvisor = new LinkButton();
                            lnkTeamAdvisor.EnableViewState = true;
                            lnkTeamAdvisor.Text = "Team Advisor" + "<br />";
                            lnkTeamAdvisor.ID = "lnkTeamAdvisor" + i.ToString();
                            PlaceHolderRoles.Controls.Add(lnkTeamAdvisor);
                            lnkTeamAdvisor.Visible = true;
                            lnkTeamAdvisor.PostBackUrl = PresentationConstant.ASPX_DMREPORTS;
                            break;

                        case (int)Helper.UserRole.RPC:
                            Session[AppConstants.ROLEID] = UserCredentialsDT.Rows[i]["RoleId"];
                            LinkButton lnkRPC = new LinkButton();
                            lnkRPC.EnableViewState = true;
                            lnkRPC.Text = "RPC" + "<br />";
                            lnkRPC.ID = "lnkRPC" + i.ToString();
                            PlaceHolderRoles.Controls.Add(lnkRPC);
                            lnkRPC.Visible = true;
                            lnkRPC.PostBackUrl = PresentationConstant.ASPX_ARDREPORTS;
                            break;

                        case (int)Helper.UserRole.RegionalManager:
                            Session[AppConstants.ROLEID] = UserCredentialsDT.Rows[i]["RoleId"];
                            LinkButton lnkRegionalManager = new LinkButton();
                            lnkRegionalManager.EnableViewState = true;
                            lnkRegionalManager.Text = "Regional Manager" + "<br />";
                            lnkRegionalManager.ID = "lnkRegionalManager" + i.ToString();
                            PlaceHolderRoles.Controls.Add(lnkRegionalManager);
                            lnkRegionalManager.Visible = true;
                            lnkRegionalManager.PostBackUrl = PresentationConstant.ASPX_RMREPORTS;
                            break;

                        case (int)Helper.UserRole.MerchAdmin:
                            Session[AppConstants.ROLEID] = UserCredentialsDT.Rows[i]["RoleId"];
                            LinkButton lnkMerchAdmin = new LinkButton();
                            lnkMerchAdmin.EnableViewState = true;
                            lnkMerchAdmin.Text = "Merch Admin" + "<br />";
                            lnkMerchAdmin.ID = "lnkMerchAdmin" + i.ToString();
                            PlaceHolderRoles.Controls.Add(lnkMerchAdmin);
                            lnkMerchAdmin.Visible = true;
                            lnkMerchAdmin.PostBackUrl = PresentationConstant.ASPX_MERCHANDISINGADMIN;
                            break;

                        default:
                            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "msg", "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert('Invalid Role.');</script>");
                            break;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }



  private String GetStoresForStoreManager_Table(Int32 iStoreManagerId)
    {
        String strDestinationPage = String.Empty;
        String strStoreNo = String.Empty;
        String strStoretypeId = String.Empty;

        String strStoretype = String.Empty;
        DataTable dtStoreDetails = null;

        StoreBL objStoreBL = new StoreBL();
        dtStoreDetails = objStoreBL.GetStoresForStoreManager_Table(iStoreManagerId);

        if (dtStoreDetails.Rows.Count != 0)
        {
            if (dtStoreDetails.Rows.Count > 1)
            {
                strDestinationPage = PresentationConstant.ASPX_CHOOSESTORE;
            }
            else
            {
                strStoreNo = dtStoreDetails.Rows[0][AppConstants.STORENO].ToString();
                strStoretypeId = dtStoreDetails.Rows[0][AppConstants.ID].ToString();
                if (dtStoreDetails.Rows[0][AppConstants.ISRETAIL].ToString().ToLower() == "true")
                {
                    strStoretype = DBConstants.RETAIL;
                }
                else
                {
                    strStoretype = DBConstants.SandR;
                }
                Session.Add(AppConstants.STORENO, strStoreNo);
                Session.Add(AppConstants.STORETYPEID, strStoretypeId);
                Session.Add(AppConstants.STORETYPE, strStoretype);
                strDestinationPage = PresentationConstant.ASPX_STOREMAIN;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "msg", "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert('You are not associated with any store.');window.location = 'SprintLogin.aspx';</script>");
        }
        return strDestinationPage;

    }
    protected void lnkAdmin_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect(PresentationConstant.ASPX_MERCHANDISINGADMIN);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
if (!IsPostBack)
```

will cause your page to NOT create the dynamic button in a postback, thus the ASP.Net framework will not find the control that raised the event.

I wonder why you don't get a ViewState exception, though.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should [create dynamic controls in the PreInit event handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). However in this case devio's answer looks like the true cause of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be better off just having the linkbutton on your page and setting the text/attribute depending on what case you're in.  Saves all the dynamic control hassle altogether.

Edit:

Sorry, just saw your foreach - maybe a link in a repeater.